# Custom Scaffolding Extension Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2019, t4, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding, t4scaffolding

I'm attempting to create a Custom Scaffold Extension for .NET Framework and Visual Studio 2019.  I do not want to overwrite the default MVC T4 templates. I'm trying to do something like:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robinliks.HappyScaffoldingforMVC5

I've found plenty of articles detailing the process for older versions of VS to include the SideWaffle projects but nothing that works with 2019.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?